# Interface implementation in C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface

I have an interface defined in `C#` project:

```
public interface IForm
{
    bool IsDisposed { get; }
    void Show();
}
```

I implemented it in a `C#` class in WinForms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IForm {  }
```

As the method `Show()` and property `IsDisposed` are already present in the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class I do not require to implement it.

But same doesn't hold true in `VB.NET`, in `VB.NET` I have to define the members, otherwise getting compile error.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Implements WindowsFormsApplication1.IForm

    Public ReadOnly Property IsDisposed1 As Boolean Implements WindowsFormsApplication1.IForm.IsDisposed
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Show1() Implements WindowsFormsApplication1.IForm.Show

    End Sub
End Class
```

Why do I have to define the interface members in VB.NET if they are already present in the base class ?

Comment: I don't see where your VB.NET class is inheriting from `System.Windows.Form`.

Comment: Two languages have different rules. This isn't surprising. If they were identical in all respects, they wouldn't *be* two languages.

Comment: @Oded: I guess he created the form with the designer (or morelikely, it was the one that is there when you create a new vb application), which means the `Inherits Form` statement is in the `Form1.Designer.vb` file.

Comment: @Pondidum, you are right.

Comment: One question. Doesn't the above VB code mean that we replace the default implementations of the `Show` and `IsDisposed` members in the `Form` class with empty procedures (`IsDisposed1`, `Show1`)? In other words, now the `Show` and `IsDisposed` members of the `Form1` simply do nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VB does not have implicit interface implementation, only explicit while C# supports both.

This means that you have to explicitly say exactly what member that implements an interface member. This adds some flexibility, for example you can make the method that implements an interface member private or protected and you can give it a name that differs from the interface member.

You can read more about the details of this here: http://ondevelopment.blogspot.se/2008/10/implementing-interfaces-in-vbnet.html

Comment: On the flipside, vb.net allows a method which implements an interface to have a visibility other than "public" or "none".  IMHO, in an inheritable class, if the visibility isn't "public" it should more often than not "protected" [typically using a slightly-modified name], since derived classes will often need to modify a method's behavior without replacing it entirely.  The way C# does things, a parent class's explicit implementation of an interface cannot be used from within a child class's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET allows you to name a function/sub differently than the function/sub that it implements. This means that you must explicitly add the `Implements <Function/Sub>` to the end of the signature.

In C# you can't do this, so the implementations "just work" without you having to add anything.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b3c4by9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The parameter types and return types of the implementing member must match the interface property or member declaration in the interface. The most common way to implement an element of an interface is with a member that has the same name as the interface

Comment: You can implement a interface explicitly in C#, the Method is given the full InterfaceName.MethodName syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use the shadows keyword if you want to override the standard methods of the Form and replace them with the ones defined in your interface otherwise you are required to use a different name as they are treated as two separate methods.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Implements IForm

    Public Shadows Property IsDisposed As Boolean Implements IForm.IsDisposed

    Public Shadows Sub Show() Implements IForm.Show
        ' replaces original method in Form class
    End Sub

End Class
```

Alternative:

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form
    Implements IForm

    Public Property IsDisposed1 As Boolean Implements IForm.IsDisposed

    Public Sub Show1() Implements IForm.Show
        Me.Show() ' Original method still exists and is accessible like this
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I really wish that `ShowDialog`, `Show` and `Close` were marked as `Overrideble` for this reason, I do hate shadowing methods :(