# C# to VB interface conversion error

Tags: c#, vb.net

Here is the C# code

```
namespace WpfApplication9.ViewModels.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITradeViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<Trade> GetTrades();
    }
}

namespace WpfApplication9.ViewModel
{
    public class TradesViewModel : BaseViewModel, ITradeViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Trade> _trades = new ObservableCollection<Trade>();

        private ICommand _saveCommand;
        private ICommand _loadCommand;

        public TradesViewModel()
        {
            _saveCommand = new SaveTradesCommand();
            _loadCommand = new LoadTradesCommand();
            _trades = GetTrades();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades { get {return _trades;} }

        public ObservableCollection<Trade> GetTrades()
        {
            if (_trades == null || _trades.Count == 0)
                _loadCommand.Execute(_trades);
            return _trades;
        }
    }
}
```

and when I convert this into VB as below,

```
Namespace WpfApplication9.ViewModels.Interfaces
    Public Interface ITradeViewModel
        Function GetTrades() As ObservableCollection(Of Trade)
    End Interface
End Namespace


Namespace WpfApplication9.ViewModel
    Public Class TradesViewModel
        Inherits BaseViewModel
        Implements ITradeViewModel

        Private _trades As New ObservableCollection(Of Trade)()

        Private _saveCommand As ICommand
        Private _loadCommand As ICommand

        Public Sub New()
            _saveCommand = New SaveTradesCommand()
            _loadCommand = New LoadTradesCommand()
            _trades = GetTrades()
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Trades() As ObservableCollection(Of Trade)
            Get
                Return _trades
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Function GetTrades() As ObservableCollection(Of Trade)
            If _trades Is Nothing OrElse _trades.Count = 0 Then
                _loadCommand.Execute(_trades)
            End If
            Return _trades
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

It will return me an error that tells me GetTrades for the interface ITradeViewModel is not implemented?

What am I doing wrong?

thanks,

Comment: you have to be explicit with vb.net - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx

Comment: VB needs your to be more explicit.  Put the cursor on the Imeplements line, tap enter and it will add the template for the required methods/members etc  `Implements ITradeViewModel.GetTrades`

Comment: thanks, so simple it was. Sometimes conversion tools even dont do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly implement the method by adding `Implements ITradeViewModel.GetTrades`:

```
    Public Function GetTrades() As ObservableCollection(Of Trade) Implements ITradeViewModel.GetTrades
        If _trades Is Nothing OrElse _trades.Count = 0 Then
            _loadCommand.Execute(_trades)
        End If
        Return _trades
    End Function
```

VB.NET, unlike C#, [does not have implicit interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105040/interface-implementation-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net).