# How does the compiler choose the target overload with two interface methods sharing the same signature except one is generic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, interface, overloading

`System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)` implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T)`, which each have a `GetEnumerator()` method (respectively):

```
Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator
Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of T)
```

Assume I have `myList` which is an instance of the `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)`; if I call `myList.GetEnumerator()`, the compiler targets `Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of T)` and `Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator` is hidden from the intellisense list.  Indeed, if I look at `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)` using ILSpy, the latter overload is completely missing.

I want to create my own collection class which implements those two interfaces, so I have to do this:

```
Class MyItemCollection
    Implements System.Collections.IEnumerable, 
        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Item)

    Private _items As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Item)

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Item) _
        Implements IEnumerable(Of Item).GetEnumerator

        Return _items.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerator _
        Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator

        Return _items.GetEnumerator()
    End Function
End Class
```

Notice that I have to use `GetEnumerator` and `GetEnumerator1` because, due to the return type difference, I can't combine them into one `GetEnumerator` method.  If I leave out `Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator` I get a compiler error.

**How does `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)` get away with *not* implementing both overloads if that's, in fact, what it's doing, or if not, how does it determine which overload it's going to present?  How can I achieve this result with my VB.NET code?**

Note: I think, as the_lotus pointed out, this has something to do with explicit interface implementation, but that doesn't exist in VB.NET like it does in C#.

Comment: Their implementation are private and have [dots in the function name](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/List@cs/1305376/List@cs). It's called [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105040/interface-implementation-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net

Comment: @the_lotus If there implementations were private, then I wouldn't be able to see either method unless I cast the instance as an `IEnumerable(Of Item)` or an `IEnumerable`, right?  Also, VB doesn't have explicit interface implementation like C# does, so if that's the answer here (given that `List(Of T)` is coded in C#) does that mean I'm out of luck in VB.NET?